# Z test vs Chi Square Test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test, inference

I am faced with the following question:

> The proportion of US smokers $(p_1)  = 136/157$.
>
> The proportion of Non-US smokers $(p_2) = 21/157$.
>
> To test $H_0 : p_1 = p_2$ versus $H_1 : p_1 > p_2$ at 5% significance, the data provides evidence to reject NULL hypothesis by using the value of ?
>
> $(a)\quad Z \quad (b)\quad \chi^2 \quad (c)\quad \text{Both }Z\text{ and }\chi^2 \quad (d)\quad \text{Neither}$.

I obtained the $\chi^2$ value as $15.10$ and $Z$ value as $3.887$ (which I can see is the square root of $\chi^2$). There are multiple questions in the paper with similar options. My guess is that since chi-square test is more appropriate for independence between variables a $Z$ test should be used here.

Comment: Take a close look at the alternative here.

Comment: Use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for typesetting math. And please add the [self-study](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) tag.

Comment: @Glen_b-ReinstateMonica Thanks, I get it now.